# comparing two strings in Android ( if-else statemente)

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am working on a login page in an Android App.

As you know, the app must check if the username and password are valid, and then grant the user access to the application.

I have used the following code:

...

```
EditText un = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username1);
EditText pw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password1);
String u = un.getText().toString();
String p = pw.getText().toString();

//////// Now on the click of the Login Button:

public void onClickL (View view){
if ( (u.equals("Android")) && (p.equals("1234"))) /////// move to a new activity

else ///////Display a warning message: Try again
}
```

when I run this code this only executes the else part. why its not executing the if part? what should I do ?

Comment: Are you aware that "Android" is different from "android"? Case matters. Also make sure that there are no spaces surrounding your strings.

Comment: Use equalsIgnoreCase instead of equals.Also try to debug your app and check the value of u and p inside click method.

Comment: Did you set your button's onClick property in the layout?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

**get the text inside Click function** like below

```
public void onClick (View view){

      String u = un.getText().toString().trim();    
      String p = pw.getText().toString().trim();

       if ((u.equals("Android")) && (p.equals("1234"))) {
            //do something
       }    
       else{
           //do something
       }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are fetching the EditText's  value while declaring the EditText. Actually you nee to fetch the Text from EditText while clicking on the button, hence you need to move you code to onClick() method like below,

```
@Override
public void onClick (View view)
{
     String u = un.getText().toString();
     String p = pw.getText().toString();
     if ( (u.equals("Android")) && (p.equals("1234"))) /////// move to a new activity
     {
         ....
     }
     else ///////Display a warning message: Try again
     {
        ....
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
public void onClickL (View view){
    u = un.getText().toString();
    p = pw.getText().toString();   
     if (  u.equals("Android")   &&  p.equals("1234") ) /////// move to a new activity
       {

       } 
        else ///////Display a warning message: Try again
       {       

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try Following code

need to clear space in username if it is available.

```
public void onClick (View view){

  String username = un.getText().toString().trim();
  String password = pw.getText().toString();

   if ((username.equals("Android")) && (password.equals("1234"))) {
        //do something
   } else{
       //do something
   }     
}
```